# VB Module - Como direcionar para um site

Tags: vb.net, vba

Olá,

Então eu testei vários métodos, porém não consegui nada com o que pretendo e então vim aqui pedir ajuda.

É o seguinte, preciso que quando acessar pelo navegador exemplo: http://www.meusite.com.br/verificador.exe , ele faça a verificação que pretendo e em seguida vá para o site que quero mas sem sair da página onde já estou, sabe sem abrir uma nova guia, e eu não consegui entender como eu conseguiria realizar tal função, se alguém souber algo parecido por favor me ajuda.

Comment: Não dá pra entender o que você quer. Aliás, é VB.NET ou VBA? São duas coisas distintas.

Comment: é vb.net. Preciso que quando o cliente acessar exemplo http://meusite.com.br/verificador.exe ele encaminhe para uma página resultado.

Comment: por exemplo eu uso um apache aqui e acesso localhost/verificador.exe ele me encaminhe para um link a minha escolha, pois eu vou por uma verificação se o cliente estiver com a licença ele sera encaminhado para a pagina de acesso